# Rearranging Columns in Descending Order using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have an issue automatically rearranging columns in a spark dataframe using Pyspark.

I'm currently summarizing the dataframe according to the aggregation below:

`df_agg = df.agg(*[sum(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`

This results in a summarized table looking something like this (but with hundreds of columns):

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | ... | col_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 | 55 | 983 | ... | integer |

I would like to **automatically** rearrange my columns so they are in descending order resulting in a data frame (using the example table above):

| col_3 | col_1 | col_2 | ... | col_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 983 | 73 | 55 | ... | integer (<55) |

Very thankful for all your support!

Best regards

Comment: Only 1 row i assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford converting to pandas, you can do this:

```
cols = df_agg.toPandas().T.sort_values(by=0, ascending=False).index.tolist()
df_agg.select(cols).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict` to the rescue.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
       (1, 72, 5, -5)
    ],
    ["c_1", "c_2", "c_3", "c_4"]  
)
dict = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))[0]
sorted_dict={k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
sorted_cols = [c for c in sorted_dict.keys()]
df.select(sorted_cols).show()
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|c_4|c_1|c_3|c_2|
+---+---+---+---+
| 72|  5|  1| -5|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Could do via to rdd conversion, sort and back to dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation to thebluephantom's solution. You can use python's built-in `sorted()` within the RDD map.

Given a dataframe (say, `data_sdf`) like following.

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  64|  63|  44|  71|  97|  99|  41|  40|  30|  42|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Use the RDD `Row.asDict()` and `sorted` within that to sort the columns based on values. It's not straightforward as the row-dict is first converted to list of tuples. The list of tuples is sorted and converted back to a dict. Lastly retain the dict-keys as a list.

```py
sorted_cols = data_sdf.rdd. \
    map(lambda r: list(dict(sorted(r.asDict().items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)).keys())). \
    collect()[0]

data_sdf.select(*sorted_cols).show()

# +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
# |col5|col4|col3|col0|col1|col2|col9|col6|col7|col8|
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
# |  99|  97|  71|  64|  63|  44|  42|  41|  40|  30|
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

---

```py
print(sorted_cols)
# ['col5',
#  'col4',
#  'col3',
#  'col0',
#  'col1',
#  'col2',
#  'col9',
#  'col6',
#  'col7',
#  'col8']
```

Comment: A variation I suggested.